# How can a React component be fully responsible for it's own data if state can't be set by async call on Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu component which passes an entity id to an entity edit form (as a prop).

If that edit form has already been mounted the `render` method is called but `componentDidMount` is not called.

If I want the edit form to be responsible for completely managing the entity, then I want it to get the full details of the entity from the server.   But I can't make an async call in `render` (is that right?) and `componentDidMount` doesn't get called when a new id is passed in.

So it seems I can't make this child responsible for getting its own data.  The parent must get the entity data and pass that in for the child to display / edit.

It feels like there is too much dependence by the child on the parent.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate()` ?

Comment: That looks like the answer.   I have done this before and forgotten.

Comment: When you use `componentDidUpdate()` you should use it carefully, it may cause a loop.

Comment: Yep.  Just did that in my code.  I used this in `componentDidUpdate`

`if (prevProps.id !== props.id) {
  const element = await get <id resource>; 
  this.setState({element: element})
}`

and everything is good.   Put `componentDidUpdate()` as the answer if you like.

Comment: it's enough :) Thank you.